# What book gives a good presentation on universal/existential generalization/instantiation?

Tags: logic, reference-request, predicate-logic, book-recommendation

> What book gives a good presentation of Universal/Existential Generalization/instantiation?

I understand EI, EG and UI; however, I'm struggling with UG, I would like a book that gives a good presentation on all of them, and specially UG.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any good textbook dealing with [Natural Deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H7). See e.g. [van Dalen](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&printsec=frontcover) and [Chiswell & Hodges](https://books.google.it/books?id=c4QSDAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: If your aim to be able to write mathematical proofs, may I humbly suggest the tutorial that comes with DC Proof 2.0 freeware. It introduces students to the basic methods of proof, including making valid generalizations. Free, downloadable proof editor and checker, and more info at my homepage: http://www.dcproof.com

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think your comment is good enough. Could you please post it as an answer? Thank you

Comment: "Logic" by Paul Tomassi.